# SQL文組立ての質問：　2つのテーブル（同レイアウト）、双方存在の場合Bテーブルから出力したい

Tags: sql

AテーブルとBテーブル　同じレイアウトのテーブルがあって、双方のテーブルにレコード（同一キーの）
が存在した場合、Bテーブル側のレコードを出力したいです。Aテーブル側のレコードは出力したくありません。

BテーブルがAテーブルの後継になる運用を目指しています。

Aテーブルにしか（当該キーの）レコードが存在しない場合は　Aテーブル側の内容を出力
Bテーブルにしか（当該キーの）レコードが存在しない場合は　Bテーブル側の内容を出力
AB双方のテーブルに（当該キーの）レコードが存在する場合は　Bテーブル側の内容を出力

こういったことを達成したいです。
システム移行でありがちな発行文ですが、お知恵を頂けませんでしょうか

当方のDBMSはMSですが、SQL文にそう大差ない認識ですので　どのDBMSの例でも良いので例を示して頂ければ幸いです。ちなみに　以下2つのSELECT文をまとめて　キーごと（USERID）のレコード出力を達成したいです。よろしくお願い致します。

```
SELECT USERID, USERNAME, LEVEL FROM TABLE_A
SELECT USERID, USERNAME, LEVEL FROM TABLE_B
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Aテーブルにしか（当該キーの）レコードが存在しない場合は　Aテーブル側の内容を出力
>   Bテーブルにしか（当該キーの）レコードが存在しない場合は　Bテーブル側の内容を出力
>   AB双方のテーブルに（当該キーの）レコードが存在する場合は　Bテーブル側の内容を出力

は

- Bテーブルの内容を出力
- Bテーブルに含まれていないキーのAテーブルの内容を出力

と簡略化することができます。含まれる・含まれないは[`IN`・`NOT IN`](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/sql/t-sql/language-elements/in-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)で表現できます。

```
SELECT USERID, USERNAME, LEVEL
FROM TABLE_B
UNION ALL
SELECT USERID, USERNAME, LEVEL
FROM TABLE_A
WHERE USERID NOT IN (SELECT USERID FROM TABLE_B)
```

Comment: 確かにそうですね、発想の転換ができれば良かったんですけれど
ありがとうございました。